# Criar objeto com array de objetos interno

Tags: javascript

Eu gostaria de criar um "molde" de objeto (talvez uma classe, talvez uma função), com possivelmente outros objetos dentro dele, e *arrays*. A estrutura que eu imagino é assim:

```
postagem: {
    titulo: "",
    autor: "",
    texto: [
        {
            linha: [{
                caractere: '', // isso deveria ser um objeto
                data: string, // objeto date?
            }],
            desfazer: ?, // objetos caractere/data
        }
    ],
}
```

Explicando:

> **postagem** deve conter: **título, autor e texto**;
>
> **texto** deve conter uma quantidade indefinida de: **linha** e **desfazer**;
>
> **linha** deve conter uma quantidade indefinida de: **caractere e data**;

---

**É possível essa construção maluca?
Como eu utilizaria esse objeto?**

A idéia era poder depois transferir os objetos instanciados dessa maneira de cá pra lá usando JSON.

Comment: Pode explicar essa parte? 
"texto deve conter uma quantidade indefinida de: linha e desfazer;"

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff texto seria um array de objetos "linha" e objetos "desfazer", na minha concepção atual

Comment: Editei a resposta, fazendo com que "linha" seja um objeto.

Comment: Quais são as variáveis que precisas saber para criar o objeto e quais são comuns?

Comment: @Sergio se eu entendi a sua pergunta, não há variáveis comuns - ao instanciar, imaginava instanciar só com título e autor - texto com linha/caractere/data seriam adicionados depois, ao longo da execução do programa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes optar por objetos ou classes, depende um pouco se queres algo passivo ou ativo. Ou seja, se quiseres somente agrupar dados, um objeto serve bem; se quiseres que cada objeto possa fazer cálculos, modificar-se ou tenha métodos então classe é melhor.

Para objetos podes fazer uma função *"factory"* (gerador/fábrica) assim:

```js
function objFactory(title, author) {
  return {
    titulo: title || '',
    autor: author || '',
    texto: [{
      linha: [{
        caractere: '',
        data: null,
      }],
      desfazer: null,
    }],
  }
}

var excerto = objFactory('Lusiadas', 'Camões');
console.log(JSON.stringify(excerto));
```

Usando classes:

```js
class Excerto {
  constructor(title, author) {
    this.titulo = title || '';
    this.autor = author || '';
    this.texto = [{
      linha: [{
        caractere: '',
        data: null,
      }],
      desfazer: null,
    }];
  }
}

var excerto = new Excerto('Lusiadas', 'Camões');
console.log(excerto.titulo);
```

Se quiseres desenvolver mais podes fazer algo assim:

```js
function objFactory(title, author) {
  return {
    titulo: title || '',
    autor: author || '',
    texto: [],
  }
}

var autor = document.querySelector('input[name="autor"]');
var titulo = document.querySelector('input[name="titulo"]');
var iniciar = document.querySelector('button');

function verificarAutoria() {
  iniciar.disabled = !autor.value.trim() || !titulo.value.trim();
}

autor.addEventListener('input', verificarAutoria);
titulo.addEventListener('input', verificarAutoria);
iniciar.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  document.body.appendChild(textarea);
  var obj = objFactory(titulo.value, autor.value);
  var linha = [];
  obj.texto.push({
    linha: linha,
    desfazer: null,
  });
  textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { // Enter, mudar a linha
      linha = [];
      obj.texto.push({
        linha: linha,
        desfazer: null,
      });
    } else {
      var caractere = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
      linha.push({
        caractere: caractere,
        data: new Date(),
      });
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="autor" />
<input type="text" name="titulo">
<button type="button" disabled>Iniciar</button>
```

**jsFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/rpohrz8q/

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que seria algo parecido com isso, tu pode ir adicionando novos objetos nos array's através do método [`push();`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

```js
var caractere = {
  nome: 'Daniel'
};
var data = new Date();
var linha = {
  caractere: [caractere],
  data: [data]
}
var desfazer = {
  caractere: [caractere],
  data: [data]
}

var postagem = {
  titulo: 'StackOverFlow',
  autor: 'Mathias',
  texto: [linha, desfazer]
};

//O mais próximo que consegui da maneira presente na pergunta:
/*var postagem = {
  titulo: "",
  autor: "",
  texto: {
    linha: {
      caractere: [],
      data: []
    },
    desfazer: {
      caractere: [],
      data: []
    }
  }
}*/

console.log(postagem.titulo);
console.log(postagem.autor);
console.log(postagem.texto[0].caractere[0].nome);
console.log(postagem.texto[0].data[0]);
```

Comment: Interessante! Vou tentar assim - na verdade "desfazer" também seria um objeto "linha", (tem a mesma estrutura, só outro nome). E construir da maneira que eu tentei na pergunta, sabe se é possível? Ah, e obrigado pela resposta! :)

Comment: Arrumei lá @DanielGomes, também deixei indicado o mais próximo que consegui deixar da ideia da pergunta :)

Comment: Gostei da sua edição! Era mais ou menos isso que eu queria - última dúvida: dá para transformar esse seu código comentado em uma `class` ou `function`, pra que eu possa instanciar vários desses objetos, ex.: `var a = new postagem("Stack", "Mathias");`?

Comment: Ah, e `linha` e `desfazer` são arrays de arrays - eu coloquei [neste fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnrbmvat/) pra testar, mas ainda estou quebrando a cabeça (sou muito burro!)